# Trendline not appearing on timeseries graph using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to using d3.js and am trying to plot a timeseries graph with a trendline. The axes are showing correctly, but I am uncertain why the trendline is not appearing. What should I change in my code to make the trendline appear? I am using d3 v4.

```
//create function to parse the date
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

//open the dataset

d3.csv("filename.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d){
    //parse the date
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value
})
visualize(data)
});


//set up SVG
var width = 1500;
var height = 800;
var padding = 30;


function visualize(dataset) {
//set ranges
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([padding,width-padding]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height-padding,padding]);

//define line
var trendline = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) {return d.date})
                    .y(function(d) {return d.value});

//create svg element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding + ")");

//scale the range of the data
xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) {return d.date}))
yScale.domain([0,d3.max(dataset, function(d) {return d.value;})])


g.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+ padding +"," + (height-padding*2) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10));

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+padding*2+",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

g.append("path")
    .data(dataset)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", trendline);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried using d3.svg.line() instead of d3.line()?

Comment: when I try that I get the following error: TypeError: d3.svg is undefined. I think d3.svg.line() is for a different version of d3

Comment: I don't have the csv file that you have so I cannot run this code, but I think your code should work fine, you need to adjust your width height and padding, because those are the main attributes that defines your line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the suggestions by @Geredo 
change this line

```
.attr("d", trendline);
```

with

```
.attr("d",trendline(data));
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

Right now your line generator...

```
var trendline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {return d.date})
    .y(function(d) {return d.value});
```

... uses the values in the dataset as they are. This is clearly incorrect, since you have dates for the `x` value (according to your scale).

The solution is simple, just use your scales in the line generator:

```
var trendline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {return xScale(d.date)})
    .y(function(d) {return yScale(d.value)});
```

Also, use `datum`, not `data`:

```
g.append("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    //etc...
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not seem to work. I am still getting the same output